# Slow WiFi speed on MacBook Pro late 2008 (A1286)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, airport

I'm using a cheap TP-Link WiFi router and i'm hitting a wall at around 30 Mbps.
I've tested with other laptops and they run fine to 100 Mbps.

I have Yosemite at the moment, and an interesting fact is that, in the past, i don't remember on what OS, i was able to hit 100 Mbps on WiFi.

Any suggestions regarding WiFi settings or chip firmware ?

[image: system information]

Comment: Mentioning the model identifier A1286 isn't very informative: MBPs 15" from mid 2008 - mid 2012 show it. How do you measure the speed? Have you tried the 5GHz range already (if the router provides it)?

Comment: My laptop is late 2008; the router doesn't have 5Ghz

Comment: I agree with @klanomath on both counts. How are you measuring the speed? Also, can you share share a screenshot of the About This Mac screen so we can be certain of the exact model you have?

Comment: Is your bluetooth on?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/4QPDj here is the about this mac screen; @Peter i've tried with both BT on and off

Comment: @Cumatru Thanks for providing the About This Mac screen. The other key to understanding your scenario is how it is you're measuring the speed. I have access to the exact same model MacBook Pro and am willing to do some tests, but would need to know the what method you're using to measure speeds.

Comment: @Monomeeth - internet connections here are very cheap and fast, so 100 Mbps can be easily topped if you have a decent PC/MAC. I have this problem when i'm download from bittorrent or via HTTP tests or downloads ( downloads either from my own ISP provider which are almost guaranteed to be fast or from any test ). I must mention that if i plug in the UTP cord, i hit 100 Mbps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you are running the latest version of Mac OS X ( get 10.7.2+)
Apply all available system and software updates available to your Mac from Apple menu > Software Update
Reset the WiFi Router
After you’re positive you’re on the newest version of OS X and have all software updates applied to the Mac in question, proceed with the solution:

Add a New Network Location & Renew DHCP Lease

Launch “System Preferences” from the  Apple menu
Select the “Network” panel
Click on the “Location” pull down menu and choose “Edit Locations…”
Click on the + plus icon to add a new network location, give it a unique name, and click “Done”
Back at the Network panel with the newly created location selected, click on “Advanced” in the bottom right corner
Click on the “TCP/IP” tab
Click on “Renew DHCP Lease” and wait for the numbers on the left to repopulate, then click “OK”
Renew DHCP in Mac OS X Lion

You should now have a stable wireless connection under Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2.

For most users the wifi stability issue was resolved with installing the latest OS X Lion updates, but in some cases is seems that old network connection profiles brought the problem forward for to the newest OS update.